# Nested looping XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, loops, while-loop

This is my XML:

```
<Scenario>
   <Steps>
      <Step Name="A">
         <Check Name="1" />
         <Check Name="2" />
      </Step>
      <Step Name="B">
         <Check Name="3" />
      </Step>
   </Steps>
</Scenario>
```

I am trying to loop through the XML elements by, for each Step, doing something with that Step's respective Check elements.  So:

```
foreach(Step step in Steps) {
   foreach(Check in step) {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

It might output something like:

```
A1
A2
B3
```

The code I'm using is:

```
foreach (XElement step in document.Descendants("Step"))
{
   // Start looping through that step's checks
   foreach (XElement substep in step.Elements())
   {
```

However it is not looping properly.  The nested loop structure above is doing something for all the Check elements for each Step, instead of just doing something for the child Check elements of each Step.  For example, the output of my code is:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
```

How can I fix my loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. See this

```
foreach (XElement step in document.Descendants("Step"))
{
    // Start looping through that step's checks
    foreach (XElement substep in step.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(step.Attribute("Name").Value + "" 
                        + substep.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A1
A2
B3
```

Comment: @gunr2171 it all depends on how the xml is. Given the example in question this is fine.

Comment: You're right... so weird, I guess it's a different problem causing the loops to output the wrong thing.